# How do I get rid of "deprecated" warnings in legacy Cocos2Dx project

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, ndk-build

I have a legacy Cocos2D game project.
When compiling Android version, I get a lot of warnings:

```
warning: 'cocos2d::CCString' is deprecated (declared at ...) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

I do not plan to update code, I just want to get rid of these warnings.
I tried to add `-Wdeprecated-declarations` and `-Wno-deprecated` to `APP_CPPFLAGS` in Application.mk, but warnings are still generated.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a final answer, but I found [this](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-disable-warning-needs-to-have-dll-interface-to-be-used-by-clients-of-class/1148).

Maybe if you find what's the code of deprecation warnings you can make an use of it.

I hope it helps.